# Java подключение библиотек

Tags: java, library

Немного не понимаю механизм подключения библиотеки, хочу подключить AGAVU, подскажите как ее добавить: достаточно в Maven добавить новую Dependency или же подгрузить библиотеку непосредственно в IDE и при высылке проекта скинуть ее с проектом, или подключить ее в IDE и добавить сразу в Maven, растолкуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: сам проект уже собираться при помощи maven?

Comment: @VladMamaev Да, собирал его уже мавеном, но потом решил доработать, подключил Agavu и функционал (подключил в dependency и просто в IDE добавил библиотеку)

Comment: достаточно было просто добавить в pom.xml . Или вопрос в том как теперь поделиться проектом чтобы человек получивший его смог без проблем собрать и запустить?

Comment: @VladMamaev да,  хотел спросить как лучше отправить, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несколько строчек с зависимостью в `pom.xml` - это несколько **байт**.

Целый `*.jar` файл с библиотекой - это несколько **мегабайт**

---

Почувствуйте разницу, как говорится!!

Для этого и придумали `maven` !! Хотя, конечно, не только для этого..